# If statement depending on time of day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to use a specific time, so far I had this

```
=IF(AND(TIME(15,45,0)<=(AW15=$A$11,$A$13)),IF(AND(TIME(15,45,0)>=(AW16=$A$13,$A$15))
```

So if before 15:45:00 I need for it to equal this logical test `AW15=$A$11,$A$13` and if after 15:45:00 to equal to `AW16=$A$13,$A$15`.

Hope it makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please give a proper example and with a link to the screenshot of your sample excel sheet.

Comment: sorry like i said I dont work with excel a lot.  For example I currently have an if statement that looks like this  =IF(AW16=$A$13,$A$15) but I would like to include a time check that if its before 15:45:00 then it need to be =IF(AW15=$A$11,$A$13) and if after 15:45:00 then it should be =IF(AW16=$A$13,$A$15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you are trying to write a nested IF statement. That is, IF A is true, THEN IF B is also true THEN return result 1, otherwise (A true, but B not true) return result 2, otherwise (A not true, B not tested) return result 3.

In Excel, this would be written as follows:
`=IF(Parameter1=Condition1,IF(Parameter2=Condition2,Result1,Result2),Result3)`

Applying it to your scenario, I think you are aiming for this:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(NOW()), MINUTE(NOW()), SECOND(NOW())) < TIME(15,45,0),
    IF(AW15=$A$11,$A$13,"Condition1.2"),
    IF(AW16=$A$13,$A$15,"Condition2.2"))
```

Note, some scenarios have not been covered by your statement, so I have written "Condition1.2" and "Condition2.2" which you can replace with additional tests or results to return.

Condition1.2 is where the time is before 15:45, but `AW15` did NOT equal `A11`.

Condition2.2 is where the time is at or after 15:45, but `AW16` did NOT equal `A13`.

You don't have to put anything in those placeholders if you don't want to, but if either of those conditions are ever met then the formula will simply return "FALSE".

Also, if you do not want the test time to be `NOW()`, then you will need to reference another cell that contains a fixed timestamp for when the row is being worked. `NOW()` is volatile, which means if you save the spreadsheet before 15:45 but then open it again after 15:45, the results you had already calculated will all change.

Comment: Thank you JoeMalpass since the needed time for comparison is not known to me as it will be individually input by someone else I believe I will use just a separate sheet with the available possibilities but I will use your statement as starting point. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to compare the time now to `15:45:00` and make a selection based on that. If so the solution is:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(NOW()), MINUTE(NOW()), SECOND(NOW())) < TIME(15,45,0),
    AW15=$A$11,$A$13, AW16=$A$13,$A$15)
```

This translates to: If the time now is before 15:45:00 then do `AW16=$A$13,$A$15` else do `AW16=$A$13,$A$15`

If you want to compare the time in a specific cell then substitute the `TIME(HOUR(NOW()), MINUTE(NOW()), SECOND(NOW()))` with a cell which has a time for example:

```
=IF(A1 < TIME(15,45,0),
    AW15=$A$11,$A$13, AW16=$A$13,$A$15)
```

Comment: the first solution looks more like I need, except that the time is not "now" that would vary, the logistic of it is the same.  "If the time entered is before 15:45:00 then do AW16=$A$13,$A$15 else do AW16=$A$13,$A$15

Comment: Will you have the time (the not `now()` time i mean ) in a specific cell? If so then your answer is the second `IF`

Comment: No I don't cause I don't necessarily know the time that it will be entered. Just the time that I need to compared it against to either give me  AW15=$A$11,$A$13 or AW16=$A$13,$A$15

Comment: Ok, where is the time going to be entered. I am assuming at a predefined cell. Use that cell then.

Comment: let me give it a try and thank you!!!!!! OKAY I tried it but i get a too many arguments were entered for this function.